# How to split text after a certain number of non-space and non-paragraph characters?

Tags: python

I would like to split up a text after a certain number of non-space and non-paragraph characters.

So far, I know that you can do this to split up a string after a total number of characters

```
cutOff = 10
splitString = oldString[0:cutOff]
```

But how do I do this so that it does not factor spaces in the character count?

Comment: Without a concrete example with input, and expected output it's impossible to answer you. You may use regex or split the text on spaces and then join it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression.  This returns a two-element tuple (list) containing the two halves of the input string broken at the desired location:

```
import re

data = """Now is  the time
for all   good men
to come"""

def break_at_ignoring_whitespace(str, break_at):
    m = re.match(r"((\s*\w){%d})(.*)" % break_at, str, re.S)
    return (m.group(1), m.group(3)) if m else (str, '')

r = break_at_ignoring_whitespace(data, 14)

print(">>" + r[0] + "<<")
print(">>" + r[1] + "<<")
```

Result:

```
>>Now is  the time
fo<<
>>r all   good men
to come<<
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `while` loop.

```
oldString = "Hello world"
cutOff = 10

i = 0
while i < cutOff and cutOff < len(oldString):
    if oldString[i] in [' ', '\n']: cutOff += 1
    i += 1

splitString = oldString[:cutOff]
```